# Why JSON_EXTRACT wildcard with LIKE% or %LIKE does not work in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7, json-extract

I need to search for data in MYSQL table with JSON data. Using `JSON_EXTRACT(@json, "$.link") LIKE '%http%'` works as expected. But `LIKE 'http%' or '%http'` dosn't!

Does it means JSON_EXTRACT cant't be used with single wildcard select matching?

EXAMPLE:

This is my JSON

```sql
set @json = '{"link": "https://www.google.com"}' ;
```

```sql
select JSON_EXTRACT(@json, "$.link") like '%com'; 
-- returns 0

select JSON_EXTRACT(@json, "$.link") like 'http%' ; 
-- returns 0

select JSON_EXTRACT(@json, "$.link") like '%google%' ; 
select JSON_EXTRACT(@json, "$.link") like '%http%' ; 
select JSON_EXTRACT(@json, "$.link") like '%com%' ; 
-- returns 1 !
```

And here are an example in Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yPvfa2UZsZLdYSxdsnecx/0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON_EXTRACT still returns JSON. It does not return "raw" values, although it might make that impression when you use it to extract an individual number, because the way JSON represents a number is compatible to SQL. That's not the case for strings.

In other words:

```
set @json = '{"link": "https://www.google.com"}' ; 

select JSON_EXTRACT(@json, "$.link");
```

returns `"https://www.google.com"`, not `https://www.google.com`, and your `LIKE` has to account for the double quotes.

To convert a JSON string to to an actual MySQL string, use [`JSON_UNQUOTE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote).

Comment: Thanks! In other words, I need to select `select json_extract(@json, "$.link") like '"http%' ; ` ! I believe, using `JSON_UNQUOTE()` will be an additional step and not recommended for performance though.

Comment: It depends on what you want. The *formally correct* approach is to always use `JSON_UNQUOTE` when handling strings, because there is no way to guarantee that the JSON string does not look like `{"link": "\u0068\u0074\u0074\u0070\u0073\u003a\u002f\u002f\u0077\u0077\u0077\u002e\u0067\u006f\u006f\u0067\u006c\u0065\u002e\u0063\u006f\u006d"}`. Once that's decoded, it's `{"link":"https://www.google.com"}`, but only the comparison with `JSON_UNQUOTE` will succeed. It's an extreme example, but it's completely valid and your code should not bug out on it.

Comment: `JSON_EXTRACT` is an expensive operation already. It involves interpreting the path, parsing the JSON, running the path to get results, and serializing those results as JSON again - for every row in your query. Don't assume that `JSON_UNQUOTE` will add too much to that already bad balance. Also - incorrect code that runs fast is not worth a whole lot.

Comment: Thinking about it, since JSON_EXTRACT involves a JSON serialization step, it might be that you will never actually get `"\u0068\u0074\u0074\u0070..."` out of it, no matter how the input string looks like. But you are still at the mercy of whatever the JSON serializer built into MySQL thinks it should do to strings, and there is more than one way to represent a string in JSON, for example when it comes to diacritics.

Comment: This is even more interesting with select on equal. Setting json value to `'{"link": "a"}';` 
will return `true` for `select json_extract(@json, "$.link") = 'a' ; select json_extract(@json, "$.link") = "a";`  but not `select json_extract(@json, "$.link") = '"a"';`

Comment: That ... doesn't make any sense. How can these be different? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tN9Sm8XSwPq959iCdYHgZa/0

Answer (score 3):

Please Try this.
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.like')) LIKE '%com%'